# How to know which view is Django context processor being called from?

Tags: django

I want to pass a set of flags in a dictionary to django templates but I'd like to set different flags for different views being called. I thought of implementing it through context processors but I am not able to figure out the way.

Say for example:

In context processor I have:

```
FLAGS = {
    'Flag1': False,
    'Flag2': False,
}
```

I want to introduce a logic say when view_method1 is called I should be able to set `FLAGS['Flag1'] = True` before rendering it to the template.

For the sake of discussion lets assume we have following context processor:

```
def user_context(request):

     FLAGS = {
    'Flag1': False,
    'Flag2': False,
}
```

Any other approach apart from this will also be appreciated. Thanks.

SOLUTION

```
view_function = resolve(request.path_info).url_name
```

or

```
view_function = resolve(request.path_info).func
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have request object available in the context processor.

The request object knows what was the result of URL dispatch in `request.resolver_match` attribute:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match